# Kinect microphone array (linux), HARK in combination with OpenNI

Tags: kinect, openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on sound-source localization for our robot. For our robot vision we use OpenNI.

In my search for software for reading the Kinect microphone array I did not found anything usefull at OpenNI. The old decrepated page says however that OpenNI supports the Kinect microphone array, http://www.ros.org/wiki/kinect.

Offtopic question:
Can one read the Kinect microphone array using OpenNI? If so how? And why is there no documentation for it (I looked really hard)?

Now because I could not figure out if OpenNI supported the Kinect microphone array I looked for other solutions. I came in contact with HARK-kinect. Which is in fact a kind of API for ROS to communicate with HARK. HARK comes with a driver for the Kinect to read out the microphone array. Now I have already build some schematics in HARK and tested it with the Kinect.

This morning when bicycling to the university, it came up with me that all the work I am doing now is totally pointless. HARK namely has a own driver for communicating with the Kinect, so does OpenNI (I presume).

Main question:
Does anybody know if both HARK and OpenNI can communicate with the Kinect at the same time?

I could imaging namely that both drivers would conflict with each other?

I hope someone can say something clever about this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48684/kinect-microphone-array-(linux),-hark-in-combination-with-openni./) by [WG-](https://answers.ros.org/users/2766/wg-/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2012-11-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With hours of pain and suffering we managed to install hark with the Kinect ALSA-drivers on our robot and i can confirm, that audio over ALSA and depth-/imagedata over OpenNI work simultaneously.

We had the whole thing, including the sound-localization demo, set up properly under electric, but now have serious problems with hark under fuerte. The documentation for hark is quite poor in my opinion and it is a lot of try and error to get it all right...

---

Followup because of the question in the comments:
The setup was several months ago and sadly isnt fully functional anymore. However the hark kinect audio driver is still working set up by this instructions: [KINECT Installation](http://winnie.kuis.kyoto-u.ac.jp/HARK/wiki.cgi?page=HARK-KINECT+Installation+Instructions)

That should be sufficient to run `audio_capture` and `audio_play` from the `audio_common` package. However in our case we had to alter the audio_capture/src/audio_capture.cpp by adding the following line:

```
  _source = gst_element_factory_make("alsasrc", "source");
+ g_object_set(G_OBJECT(_source), "device", "hw:1", NULL);
  _convert = gst_element_factory_make("audioconvert", "convert");
```

The `hw:1` part may change, depending on the index of your kinect soundcard, seen by `cat /proc/asound/cards`.

For the ROS part of hark we followed [this tutorial](http://winnie.kuis.kyoto-u.ac.jp/HARK/wiki.cgi?page=HARK-ROS-TURTLEBOT), but parts of that dont seem to work with fuerte anymore. I were not able to get it running again till now. But since its not my main focus of research, i think i will not dig any deeper in trying to fix this. If anyone else manages to get it working under fuerte, i would be very pleased to read about the steps. :)

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2012-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2012-11-21**:
Hello @Ben_S.  It would be awesome if you would post a quick HOW-TO that finally worked for you under ROS Electric.  You could save the rest of us more hours of pain and suffering! :-)

**Comment by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) on 2012-11-21**:
I have added some information to the answer. :)

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2012-11-21**:
@Ben_S Fantastic--thanks!

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2012-11-21**:
Thanks for posting more information about this! I was trying to get it working too: http://answers.ros.org/question/43143/capturing-kinect-audio/

**Comment by [WG-](https://answers.ros.org/users/2766/wg-/) on 2012-11-26**:
Thank you very much for your indept information @Ben_S!